# Changing all buttons class on condition with JS or JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with buttons:

```
<div id="buttonWrapper">
<button id="x"> X </button>
<button id="y"> Y </button>
<button id="z"> Z </button>
</div>
```

When you enter the page, there is a JQuery function that load userPreferences to a table called options. It's simple table, where buttons id from above have a value.

```
options = {x: "1", y: "1", z: "0"}
```

and I want to change class of elements on condition: when in options value is 1 button gets class 'active'. I got something like this:

```
$("#buttonWrapper").find("button", function () {
                if (options[$(this).attr("id")] != null && options[$(this).attr("id")] == "1"){

                    $(this).className += " active";
                };
                return false;
            })
```

and It doesn't work. No errors, just simply doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

On same page I have second part of this function, that attaches action on click to buttons:

```
.click(function () {
                modalPreferencesSave($(this).attr("id"), $(this).hasClass("active") ? "0" : "1");
                return false;
            });
```

and second part works like charm - action is assigned, and works just fine. Only adding style won't work:/

So the whole function looks like this :

```
$("#buttonWrapper").find("button", function () {
                if (options[$(this).attr("id")] != null && options[$(this).attr("id")] == "1"){

                    $(this).className += " active";
                };
                return false;
            }).click(function () {
            modalPreferencesSave($(this).attr("id"), $(this).hasClass("active") ? "0" : "1");
            return false;
        });
```

First part - don't work - don't change style,, second part successfully adds onClick action

Comment: use `$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: Do you check your console (CTRL+SHIFT+i in chrome or firefox) to see what the error is?

Comment: @Cagy79 he already wrote that there is no error.

Comment: yes - I checked console - it was the first thing I did - no errors

Comment: You cannot pass a function as a parameter with find. Instead, you should use find("button").filter(function() {...});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#buttonWrapper button").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

The `#buttonWrapper button` selector selects all the buttons that are children to the element with id `buttonWrapper`, while `each` method iterates over them.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ceyc0mb/)

Comment: ok - it works :) thank you, for explainig the difference:) one question - so why second part worked? onClick actions was working well - with right parameters and everything, but for changing style I need to use each??

Comment: @LuciusSnow, Second part works as It was correct syntax, as I have mentioned `.find()` doesn't have a callback so it will not work

Comment: According to the `find` method documentation, it receives only a single parameter: the selector, while you passed a second parameter, an anonymous function which was never executed because nobody calls it (see https://api.jquery.com/find/). Now the `onClick` part: the `find` method returns an array with the found elements, i.e. your buttons, and when you call `.click` function, then its callback is applied on all the elements. See the updated fiddle using `find`: http://jsfiddle.net/zkzv9g0f/1/

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.each()` on the buttons. Then you can do a simple check if the option is 1 or 0. The else is not really needed in your case I think, but I love having it, to be sure that 0 has no active class

```
$("#buttonWrapper button").each(function () {         
    if (options[$(this).attr('id')] == '1')
        $(this).addClass('active');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `addClass`:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

instead of

```
$(this).className += " active";
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't have a callback so it will not work. I would recommend you to use use [`$.fn.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and then [`$.fn.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var options = {
    x: "1",
    y: "1",
    z: "0"
  };
  $("#buttonWrapper button").filter(function() {
    return options[$(this).attr("id")] != null && options[$(this).attr("id")] == "1";
  }).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonWrapper">
  <button id="x">X</button>
  <button id="y">Y</button>
  <button id="z">Z</button>
</div>
```